# Byte array to image in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmapfactory

I have a linear byte array whose values I want to set as pixels of an image. The byte array length is 4800 and I want it to be displayed as a 80x60 image with pixel values set row-wise one after the other. I know that BitmapFactory helps to handle such tasks but how do I specify the height and width of the image?

Comment: "whose values I want to set as pixels of an image" So you have one pixel = 1 byte? What format is that? Grayscale? Palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you've got is a byte array with the colors for the pixels in a Bitmap.  If so, you will probably want to use the [setPixels()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 60, myConfig);

bmp.setPixels(myPixelData, 0, 80, 0, 0, 80, 60);
```

Comment: But this requires, not a array of bytes but an array of ints, each of which represents a packed color.

Comment: ah, good point, I overlooked that, guess we need clarification from the OP